# C# How to use interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

This is a relatively straight forward question. But I was wondering what the correct usage is for accessing a method inside a separate project through the use of an interface.

**Project**: `Test.ClassLibrary`

**Interface**:

```
public interface ITest
{
    string TestMethod();
}
```

**Class**:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public string TestMethod()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

**Project:** `Test.Web`

**Controller**:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ITest test;
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(test.TestMethod());
    }

}
```

The above returns a `NullReferenceException`. I'm assuming it's because the controller gets to the interface, and doesn't know where to go next.

What's the best way to fix this? Do I have to reference the `Test` class in the controller or can I some how get away with only having a reference to `ITest`?

Comment: Do you actually have an _instance_ of `ITest` into your `test` variable? If `test == null`, you'll get that error, and it doesn't have anything related to your `ITest` interface

Comment: Edited the question: I forgot to write : ITest with the Test class declaration

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: This has nothing to do with interfaces.

Comment: How does it not? I'm asking how to use access a method through an interace without referencing the class that holds that method

Comment: It has nothing to do with interfaces because the exception you are getting is not caused by the fact that you are using an interface. Does the code start working if you change the type of the controller's private test field from ITest to Test?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- You never instantiate `ITest test`, you only declare it.
- Your `Test` class doesn't inherit from the interface.

You need to update your class declaration

```
public class Test : ITest // interface inheritance 
{
```

And in your controller, instantiate `test`.

```
ITest test = new Test();
```

As you get further along, you'll want to explore techniques for injecting the `Test` instance into the controller so that you do not have a hard dependency upon it, but just on the interface `ITest`. A comment mentions IoC, or Inversion of Control, but you should look into various *Dependency Inversion* techniques techniques (IoC is one of them, *dependency injection*, etc).

Comment: Or instead of instantiating Test you could use an IoC Container to resolve the concrete class for ITest.

Comment: This works, but it still depends on the Test class. Can you elaborate on the other techniques if they avoid this?

Comment: @rudeovskizebear, I'll be honest and say that the ASP.NET MVC model is not something I use, but googling MVC + Dependency Injection returns a great many results, and apparently they made it easier in ASP.NET MVC 3. Perhaps a good place to start is [this blog series](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. You got me on the right path. I found Unity.Mvc3 for easy dependency: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-the-unity.mvc3-nuget-package-to-reconcile-mvc3-unity-and-idisposable

Answer (score 5):

The class needs to read:

```
public class Test : ITest
```

in its declaration.

Comment: Interface methods do not need to be declared abstract. In fact, they cannot have *any* modifiers.

Comment: The code is missing some sort of object creation (new, IoC container, factory, etc..) for Test()

Comment: Yes, I missed that on my initial reading.  Need to initialize the object like so: `private Test test = new Test()`

Answer (score 4):

First off, you need to have your `Test` class inherit/implement `ITest`.

```
class Test : ITest
{
    public string TestMethod() { return "test"; }
}
```

Then, in your controller class, you need to initialize `test` -- whether directly, or in the constructor.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ITest test = new Test();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content(test.TestMethod());
    }
}
```

Although in many cases, you should prefer to create the `ITest` outside of the constructor and pass it in or something.

Answer (score 2):

#### *What ?*

Interfaces are basically a contract that all the classes *implementing* the Interface should follow. They looks like a class but has no implementation.

In `C#` Interface names by convention is defined by Prefixing an 'I' so if you want to have an interface called shapes, you would declare it as `IShapes`

#### *Now Why ?*

#### **`Improves code re-usability`**

Lets say you want to draw `Circle`, `Triangle.`  
You can group them together and call them `Shapes`and have methods to draw `Circle` and `Triangle`
But having concrete implementation would be a bad idea because tomorrow you might decide to have 2 more `Shapes` `Rectangle` & `Square`. Now when you add them there is a great chance that you might break other parts of your code.

*With Interface you isolate the different implementation from the Contract*

---

#### ***How to use them ?***

*Usage Scenario Day 1*

You were asked to create an App to Draw Circle and Triangle

```
interface IShapes
{
   void DrawShape();
}

class Circle : IShapes
{
    
    public void DrawShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation to Draw a Circle");
    }
}

class Triangle : IShapes
{
    public void DrawShape()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implementation to draw a Triangle");
    }
}
```

```
static void Main()
{
     List <IShapes> shapes = new List<IShapes>();
     shapes.Add(new Circle());
     shapes.Add(new Triangle());

     foreach(var shape in shapes)
     {
         shape.DrawShape();
     }
}
```

*Usage Scenario Day 2*

If you were asked add `Square` and `Rectangle` to it, all you have to do is create the implentation for it in `class Square: IShapes` and in `Main` add to list `shapes.Add(new Square());`