# How can I force a child to call a parent method?

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have a base class with a method.  I want to force all children of this class to call this base method somewhere in their code.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void BaseMethod()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class ChildClass1 : BaseClass
{
    public void ChildMethod()
    {
        BaseMethod();
    }
}

public class ChildClass2 : BaseClass
{
    public void ChildMethod()
    {
        //Doesn't call BaseMethod();
    }
}
```

So I want `ChildClass1` to be fine, but I want `ChildClass2` to throw an error.

The reason I want to do this is because my base class has a value that I don't want to forget to implement in my child class.  For example, if I am making a bunch of enemies for a game, and the Enemy class has a speed modifier, I don't want to forget to include that in all of the children methods:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public float x;
    public float y;

    private float speed;

    public float GetSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    public void SetSpeed(float speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}

public class Goomba : Enemy
{
    public void Move()
    {
        x += 5 * GetSpeed();
    }
}

public class Turtle: Enemy
{
    public void Jump()
    {
        y += 5;  //This is wrong.  I forgot to adjust for speed.
        //y += 5 * GetSpeed();  This is what I want to force myself to do
    }
}
```

Although it is not actually for movement.  This is an oversimplification.  The base class contains ability modifiers, where the children class are unique abilities that use the modifiers.

How can I structure my code such that a child is required to call a specific parent method somewhere in the code?

Comment: You define it as an interface

Comment: Forgetting stuff is not a good reason to change your code. Just remember it next time. Would you replace your plain door with some high tech security system, just because you forgot to lock them one time?

Comment: You could use events -- but it seems silly to me.

Comment: You could create an ability class that takes a function (lambda) as a construction parameter and then has a method "run" that does what you want first and any cleanup you need.

Comment: I think you need to use interface, take a look here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx  and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762291/c-sharp-how-to-use-interfaces

Comment: There are lots of questions already on Stack Overflow discussing the question of ensuring derived classes implement specific functionality. In your question it is a) not clear what research you've already done, if any, and why that research didn't turn up results that suit your needs, and b) it is not really even clear what specifically you're trying to do, because the code example is "an oversimplification". Please provide a good [mcve], noting that _simplification_ is good and necessary, but _oversimplification_ is bad.

Comment: As far as the specific example you did provide goes, your concern is that these are "completely different abilities", but in reality I don't see them as "completely different". You show one ability that affects the X component and one that affects the Y, but these both generalize into a single ability that affects position. It seems to me it would make more sense to express this generalization in code, letting the derived classes specify a movement vector (for direction), and having the base class determine the magnitude of the movement, based on input from the derived class.

Comment: @Hogan great idea! i think i may do that

Comment: @Evorlor -- I added some example code as my answer.

Comment: @Hogan that's not what I thought you meant. That won't work for me. But my interpretation of your suggestion might

Comment: @Evorlor - sure, but don't discount the pattern I'm showing... it is a darn good one and super powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TemplateMethod design pattern

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void BaseMethod()
    {
          DoSomething();
          TemplateMethod();

    }
    protected abstract void TemplateMethod();     
}
```

So you make your derived classes implement the template method, but clients of that class call the BaseMethod method. This forces the DoSomething() bit to execute but allows the derived classes to include their own logic.

So a simple example in the case of enemy (obvs adapt so it meets your needs).

```
public abstract class Enemy
{
    public float x;
    public float y;

    private float speed;

    public float GetSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    public void SetSpeed(float speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        x += GetMovementAmount() * GetSpeed();
    }

    public abstract decimal GetMovementAmount();
}

public class Goomba : Enemy
{
    public void GetMovementAmount()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

public class Turtle: Enemy
{
    public void GetMovementAmount()
    {
        return 6;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an actual attempt to answer the question but it could probably better be a comment or a hint. Can you edit and add / improve it?

Comment: Thank you.  But this does not work for me.  Because I want to call the method from within another method, like in my example above.

Comment: This should work in any situation @Evorlor, why can't you use it?

Comment: How would I use this with my Enemy example above?

Comment: You could put move on the base class, and have that call a template method to get the 5 part of your equation. That way they all call getspeed, but can adapt the movement to what they need.

Comment: That's my bad...my example was overly simple. This will not work for my more complex real situation. It is actually a "ability modifier" in the base class, where the children class have completely unique abilities that use this modifier.

Comment: Ah so you could perhaps invert this, and take the result of "GetSpeed()" into the template. You could still forget to use it, but at least you always pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class ability.  It will allow you to control what happens when it is run and the user gets to make the run do whatever they want.

```
public class Ability
{
   Action myAct { get; set; }

   public Ability(Action inAct)
   {
      myAct = inAct;
   }

   public Run()
   {
     DoStuffBefore();
     myAct();
     DoStuffAfter();
   }   

}
```

Comment: Either I do not understand, or this does not answer the question.

Comment: I guess you are asking a different question.

Comment: @Evorlor - see new answer

Answer (score 0):

You could rearrange the code so that changing the position is possible only in base class:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public float x { get; private set; }
    public float y { get; private set; }

    private float speed;

    public Move(float dx, float dy)
    {
        x += dx * speed;
        y += dy * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's my bad...my example was overly simple.  This will not work for my more complex real situation.  It is actually a "ability modifier" in the base class, where the children class have completely unique abilities that use this modifier.

Comment: @Evorlor, then you should close this question (either delete it or accept an answer) and ask another more detailed question.